# Need to Replace Old URL with New URL in Revolution Slider

Tags: wordpress

We have cloned a WordPress site and replaced the urls using Velvet URLs. But the Revolution Slider images url are not replaced yet. Please let me know if any solutions are there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a option in slider settings to change the **Replace URL**. Please check the screenshot attahced. Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: Great Please select the answer, if it works for you..please dont forget to upvote my answer.

Comment: Just a FYI.
This answer is outdated, and the option no longer exists

Answer (score 6):

This will work for anybody still looking for this solution. It happened to me that I needed to change the base URL on slider revolution.

1. Export to PC
2. Unpack the zip
3. Open the slider_export.txt in notepad++
4. find and replace the URL, save and repack
5. Delete the slider, and import the new one. BINGO!

P.S When changing directory, remember to escape the forward slash "/"

Best regards.

Comment: What do you export to PC the SQL or what?

Comment: There is an option to export slides in RevSlider as zip files.

You can refer to [this guide](https://visualmodo.com/knowledgebase/how-to-import-revolution-slider-demo-sliders/).

Comment: @kataliya-torres  could you please upvote my answer as the accepted answer no longer works.

Comment: This is the only way to do it if you don't want to fiddle with the escaped characters in Better Search and Replace plugin (which is fine for other URLs that need to be changed when moving a site).
So Slider Revoliution saves URLs like this: `https:\\/\\/mytestsite.com\\/sites\\/design6` and need to be replaced e.g. like this: `https:\\/\\/mylivesite.com`

Comment: Export **wp_revslider_slides** as SQL, search and replace. Delete all items in wp_revslider_slides. Delete the `CREATE TABLE `wp_revslider_slides`...` code block in edited SQL file and paste the INSERT INTO... code into phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 3):

For Slider Revolution 6, the feature has changed place.

You need to get the Domain Switch addon which is available on the main revolution slider page.

Simply browse to addons and look for DS (Domain Switch)

After installing, you'll be able to find/replace the url.

Comment: This may work but its not free. PhpMyAdmin can accomplish the same thing and you only need to edit the `wp_revslider_slides` table fields in the column `params` and `layers`. Be careful not to forget the escape characters used. I wish search and replace plugin would have a option for this.

Answer (score 1):

For those who got Revolution Slider as part of a theme and therefore don't have a purchase code.

Use a plugin like Better Search Replace to update the URLs.

Be aware that Revolution Slider escapes certain characters.

So https://example.com/
Is saved as https://example.com/

Answer (score 0):

PhpMyAdmin can accomplish the same thing and you only need to edit the wp_revslider_slides table fields in the column params and layers. Be careful not to forget the escape characters used. I wish search and replace plugin would have a option for this escape setting.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin and activate it.

Then search for youroldsite.com and replace with yournewsite.com then select all tables.

NOTE: Make sure that you have checked "Run as Dry run" to see number of changes occures before update the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `wp_revslider_slides` 
SET `layers` = 
REPLACE(`layers`,'www.oldurl.com','www.newurl.com');
```

Please note:

1. Replace your table name if it is different
2. Use your TLD without slashes (this method will not work for changing https:// as the slashes are escaped in the table content)
3. When you change your URL, you're likely going to have issues with RevSlider still using the old URL in their settings, thus causing AJAX issues and issues editing.  Using their "DOMAIN SWITCHING" add-on is recommended instead.